# enqueue the scripts

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I have a template that has been hardcoded in the header and it needs to be Enqueued. I don't know what to do and the template provider is giving me the run around. JQueries won't work because of it. I installed the Q&A plugin it won't work properly because of this script. If I delete the script. Q&A works but my menu appearance is gone:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/PIE.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/cusel-min-2.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var params = {
        changedEl: "#zip, #zip1, #zip2, #zip3, #zip4, #zip5, #zip6, #zip7, #zip8, #zip9, #zip10, #zip11",
        scrollArrows: true
    }

    cuSel(params);
     $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery$('div.sel-data').last().css('margin-left','0');
     });
</script>


<!-- superfish menu -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
                animation:   {opacity:'show', height:'show'},
                speed:       'fast',                          // faster animation speed 
                autoArrows:  false,                           // disable generation of arrow mark-up 
                dropShadows: false                            // disable drop shadows 
            });
 });
  </script>
    <!-- /superfish menu -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/Bebas_Neue_400.font.js"></script>
```

This is what dalton wrote from Q&A.

> Your theme is hard-coding a link to the jQuery library in the header.
>   You will need to contact your theme developer and ask them to properly
>   enqueue the scripts instead or your site will have problems with any
>   jQuery based plugins.

I don't know what to do or where to start. Any help would be wonderful

My site is www.halseyschools.com

Comment: `js.js` :) very original file name... Is this jQuery, because I don't see any reference to it?

Answer (score 3):

Add your script to a file inside your Theme root, e.g. `/js/my-script-name.js`.

In `functions.php`, put add a function to enqueue your script:

```
function mytheme_enqueue_some_script() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $scriptsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script-name.js';
        wp_register_script( 'my-script-name', $scriptsrc );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-name' );
    }
}
```

Then, hook that function into the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_some_script' );
```

If your script is dependent on any other scripts, we can add that information to the `wp_register_script()` call.

For further reading:

- [`wp_register_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)
- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)